# How to update header in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, header, ide

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 and when I copy some class I end up with my co-worker header instead of mine. I always need to copy paste mine and update date and time info manually.

Is there a way to update the header to mine (Define in "File and Code Templates")? Just alike the insert copyright function which work fine for updating an existing copyright.

I've seen some using the copyright to input both copyright and header but my company coding style specified that the header need to be under package and import statement. While copyright need to be on top of all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please vote for [IDEA-60148](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60148)

Comment: Well, if you copied the class, you're not really the author... ;)

Comment: ...anyway, this sounds like an ideal case for an `intellij-plugin`. It's not hard to write one yourself, otherwise for 200 bounty I could be tempted to write one for you.

Comment: Vikingsteve: Yes but at least I need to add a second @author field in the case I use a lot of the original class. But usually I copy a class to use it as a template not to add some code duplication to the project :-)